# Compare 2 folders over internet

Tags: windows, ftp, sync

I want to use a comparison tool (i.e. Winmerge, Beyond Compare) to sync two folder over internet.

The first folder is on the local PC, the second one is on a remote PC. Both the PC use Windows 10. They are not on the same network.

I can install any software on both of them. Which solution may work and how?

Installing a FTP Server?

Using a VPN? → how?

Using IIS? → how?

Installing an utility? → which one?

Is there a Window native solution for this task?

Comment: Since they are on a different network, you would need a VPN connection, and ensure the local firewalls allow a connection from the other machine.  I did this a while back with Sync Back Pro and so Beyond Compare should work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up SFTP or FTP server on one of the machine to exchange the files.

See [Best way to transfer files from Windows to Windows via Internet](https://superuser.com/q/966163/213663).

---

Once you have the server set up, you can use many applications for the synchronization. Many synchronization tools support SFTP or FTP. And conversely, some SFTP and FTP clients do support synchronization.

For example my SFTP/FTP client, [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/), has [synchronization functionality](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_synchronize_full) built-in.

Comment: Which is better? VPN, ssh or ftp?

Comment: SFTP is better than FTP. VPN is hard to compare. If you need the file transfer only, SFTP will be easier to setup.